# Unit Test Problem with assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to test for an exception.

I have:

```
def test_set_catch_status_exception(self):
    mro = self.mro
    NEW_STATUS = 'No such status'
    self.assertRaises(ValueError,mro.setStatus(NEW_STATUS))
```

I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_set_catch_status_exception (__main__.TestManagementReviewGoalGetters)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ManagementReviewObjective.py", line 68, in test_set_catch_status_exception
    self.assertRaises(ValueError,mro.setStatus(NEW_STATUS))
  File "/Users/eric/Dropbox/ManagementReview.py", line 277, in setStatus
    raise ValueError('%s is not in the list of allowed statuses: %s' % (status,LIST_OF_STATUSES))
ValueError: No such status is not in the list of allowed statuses: ['Concern or Delay', 'On Track', 'Off Track/Needs Attention']

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`self.assertRaises` expects a function `mro.setStatus`, followed by an arbitrary number of arguments: in this case, just `NEW_STATUS`. `self.assertRaises` assembles its arguments into the function call `mro.setStatus(NEW_STATUS)` inside a `try...except` block, thus catching and recording the `ValueError` if it occurs.

Passing `mro.setStatus(NEW_STATUS)` as an argument to `self.assertRaises` causes the `ValueError` to occur before `self.assertRaises` can trap it.

So the fix is to change the parentheses to a comma:

```
self.assertRaises(ValueError,mro.setStatus,NEW_STATUS)
```

Comment: I am using python 3.3 interpreter in pycharm IDE. What if I want to pass arguments to the function under test and also include a message in case the desired error is not raised ? Example - `self.assertRaises(ValueError, person.set_age_method, -10, "Error: Person's age cannot be negative.")` With this, I get an exception: `set_age_method takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. How do I fix this ? Btw, the docs for this assertion don't clearly tell you how to do it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises . What is **kwds ?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you're using `factory boy`, this package doesn't allow the exception to be raised to the assert level which will always fail