# Django - Unit test an object has been deleted - how to use assertRaise / DoesNotExist exception

Tags: django, unit-testing, exception, delete-row, assertraises

I would lioke some help to unit test a function that deletes an object in a Django app

**The problem**
I display a list of values, it includes a bin icon to delete one value, and my view seems to work fine (at least according to the test I made).
How can I unit test it? I'm not able to find out the right way to do yet.
I searched the web and found the `DoesNotExist` exception, but I'm afraid I'm not able to use it, as I got a `matching query does not exist` error.
Could you please advise me on how to proceed?

**What I tried**
Here is my current whole code for the test:

```
class TestAdmUsers(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.company = create_dummy_company("Société de test")
        self.usr11 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user11")
        self.usr13 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user13")
        self.usr14 = create_dummy_user(self.company, "user14")
        self.client.force_login(self.user_staff.user)

    def test_delete_user(self):
        test_usercomp_id = self.usr13.id
        url = reverse("polls:adm_delete_user", args=[self.company.comp_slug, self.usr13.id])
        response = self.client.get(url, follow=True)
        self.assertRaises(UserComp.DoesNotExist, UserComp.objects.get(id=test_usercomp_id))
```

The test log is the following:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_delete_user (polls.tests_admin.TestAdmUsers)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mes documents\Informatique\Developpement\Votes AG\projet_votes\polls\tests_admin.py", line 136, in test_delete_user
    self.assertRaises(UserComp.DoesNotExist, UserComp.objects.get(id=test_usercomp_id))
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
polls.models.UserComp.DoesNotExist: UserComp matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.763s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I made other tests like this one:

```
    def test_delete_user(self):
        url = reverse("polls:adm_delete_user", args=[self.company.comp_slug, self.usr13.id])
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertContains(response, self.usr12.user.username)
        self.assertNotContains(response, self.usr13.user.username)
```

that leads to this:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_delete_user (polls.tests_admin.TestAdmUsers)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mes documents\Informatique\Developpement\Votes AG\projet_votes\polls\tests_admin.py", line 136, in test_delete_user
    self.assertNotContains(response, self.usr13.user.username)
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 465, in assertNotContains
    self.assertEqual(real_count, 0, msg_prefix + "Response should not contain %s" % text_repr)
AssertionError: 1 != 0 : Response should not contain 'user13'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or this one:

```
    def test_delete_user(self):
        test_usercomp_id = self.usr13.id
        url = reverse("polls:adm_delete_user", args=[self.company.comp_slug, self.usr13.id])
        response = self.client.get(url, follow=True)
        self.company.refresh_from_db()
        self.usr13.refresh_from_db()
        users = UserComp.get_users_in_comp(self.company.comp_slug)
        self.assertContains(response, self.usr12.user.username)
        self.assertNotContains(users, self.usr13)
```

with the following result:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_delete_user (polls.tests_admin.TestAdmUsers)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mes documents\Informatique\Developpement\Votes AG\projet_votes\polls\tests_admin.py", line 137, in test_delete_user
    self.usr13.refresh_from_db()
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 628, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
polls.models.UserComp.DoesNotExist: UserComp matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And this latest one that uses a class method:

```
    def test_delete_user(self):
        current_username = self.usr13.user.username
        url = reverse("polls:adm_delete_user", args=[self.company.comp_slug, self.usr13.id])
        response = self.client.get(url, follow=True)
        self.company.refresh_from_db()
        self.usr13.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertContains(response, self.usr12.user.username)
        self.assertNotContains(UserComp.get_users_in_comp(self.company.comp_slug), self.usr13)
```

but the result is still an error:

```
`======================================================================
ERROR: test_delete_user (polls.tests_admin.TestAdmUsers)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mes documents\Informatique\Developpement\Votes AG\projet_votes\polls\tests_admin.py", line 137, in test_delete_user
    self.usr13.refresh_from_db()
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 628, in refresh_from_db
    db_instance = db_instance_qs.get()
  File "C:\Users\Christophe\.virtualenvs\projet_votes-onIieQ0I\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
polls.models.UserComp.DoesNotExist: UserComp matching query does not exist.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Related application code**
Here is the code for the view:

```
def adm_delete_user(request, comp_slug, usr_id):
    del_usr = User.objects.get(pk=usr_id)
    msg = "Utilisateur {0} {1} supprimé.".format(del_usr.last_name, del_usr.first_name)
    User.objects.get(pk=usr_id).delete()

    messages.success(request, msg)
    return redirect("polls:adm_users", comp_slug=comp_slug)
```

And the model:

```
class UserComp(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Utilisateur")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Société")
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^0[0-9]([ .-]?[0-9]{2}){4}$', message=("Format de numéro de téléphone invalide"))
    phone_num = models.CharField("numéro de téléphone", validators=[phone_regex], max_length=14, null=True, blank=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField("administrateur", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.user.last_name, self.user.first_name)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Liens Utilisateurs / Sociétés"
        verbose_name_plural = "Liens Utilisateurs / Sociétés"

    @classmethod
    def create_usercomp(cls, user, company, phone_num='', is_admin=False):
        """ Create a new UserComp """
        usr_comp = UserComp(user=user, company=company, phone_num=phone_num, is_admin=is_admin)
        usr_comp.save()
        return usr_comp

    @classmethod
    def get_users_in_comp(cls, comp_slug):
        user_list = cls.objects.filter(company__comp_slug=comp_slug)
        return user_list
```

**Complementary search results**
Finally, I found some posts here that oriented my tests, but I wasn't able to find the solution:

- [The most important to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129507/how-do-you-test-that-a-python-function-throws-an-exception) leads me to `assertRaise()` test
- Unfortunately, [the one that asked how to use this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877134/testing-in-python-how-to-use-assertraises-in-testing-using-unittest) has been closed, and referred to the previous one, but actually there is no information on how to proceed
- This [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304642/unit-test-problem-with-assertraises) asking about the exception, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527983/django-unit-test-matching-query-does-not-exist) related to the error message did not give me any additional information.

Comment: In your view `adm_delete_user` you have `User.objects.filter(pk=usr_id).delete()`. This line is error prone because `.filter()` return a *list* not an *object*

Comment: What do you propose to replace?

Comment: `User.objects.get(pk=usr_id).delete()`

Comment: What impact on unit tests? Shall I change something?

Comment: Btw, one other key difference between `.get()` and `.filter()` is that the former might raise an exception, which is not the case of the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assertRaises` takes a *callable* as its (optional) second argument.
Since `.get(...)` is not a callable, you should use the context manager form instead:

```py
with self.assertRaises(UserComp.DoesNotExist): 
    UserComp.objects.get(id=test_usercomp_id)
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works fine! I did not know this syntax (and I thought my comment was posted when I raised your answer as solving my problem =))